# table i created is not showing in SSMS even after refreshing

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view, ssms

i saved a table in my SSMS database but its not showing even after i refresh it. any idea what should be done??

Comment: SSMS is for the MS SQL Server family. It doesn't work with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reconnect and asure yourself that you are creating table rather than temporary table which disapear after closing or interupting session.

1. When reconnect will help. It means that table was created but only view of it wasn't available yet.
2. Data from temporary table begin name with `#` sign. To check if you using temporary table you can perform code shown below:

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#yourtablename') is null 
        PRINT N'Temporary table is not created';
    if object_id('tempdb..#yourtablename') is not null 
        PRINT N'Temporary table is created';
    if object_id('dbo.yourtablename') is null
        PRINT N'Normal table is not created';
    if object_id('dbo.yourtablename') is not null 
        PRINT N'Normal table is created';
```

Make sure that you are in the database where you previously created the table

Answer (score 0):

A couple of basics you can try for this:

- Try running:

  SELECT * FROM [<YOUR_DATABASE>..<YOUR_TABLE>];

  If an exception is returned, the table did not create.
- In the left sidebar, expand:

  Databases > your db > Tables

  Right-click tables and press 'refresh'. See if it appears in the list.
  If not, the table did not create.